# React equivalent of a recursive ngReadOnly/ngDisabled in angular

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I read that in Angular, you can apply `ngReadOnly` or `ngDisabled` directive to a form field and it will convert it to a read only element.

I want to do something similar in React.  Except, if I apply a directive or class or attribute like `rctReadOnly` on a container element such as `<div>`, `<form>`, `<fieldset>`, I want to **recursively** go through all child elements and:

- convert form fields to read only equivalent
- remove all html elements that have the class `.action-^`, for example `.action-add`, `.action-delete`, `.action-bulk-update` etc...

How do I achieve this in React?

Comment: My first reaction would be to create a [higher order component](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775) and put the logic in that, but it won't be magic so all components that wish to support it must be decorated with the HOC. And you'd have to make sure they pass that prop to all their children. It sounds like a pretty complicated thing to put together.